# SQL Update statement with aggregate count

Tags: sql-server

I am getting the following error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

For this query:

```
UPDATE b 
SET b.Products = (SELECT COUNT(pf.Product_Family_ID) 
                  FROM Product_Families pf
                  INNER JOIN Products p ON pf.Product_Family_ID = p.Product_Family_ID
                  INNER JOIN Brands b2 on pf.BrandID = b2.Brand_ID
                  WHERE 
                      pf.Discontinued = 0 
                      AND pf.Live = 0 
                      AND p.Inventory > 0
                      AND pf.Brand <> ''
                  GROUP BY 
                      b2.Brand, b2.Brand_ID) 
FROM Brands b
INNER JOIN Product_Families pf2 ON b.Brand_ID = pf2.BrandID
WHERE
    b.Brand_ID = pf2.BrandID
```

I know I am missing just a little something. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Look at your subquery here. It is returning the count for every Brand, Brand_ID but you are trying to use it as the value for your update.

Comment: Exactly as Sean said. Run your subquery on its own and you'll notice it returns multiple records - yet you're trying to set *one* field equal to it. Also, I don't believe your final `WHERE` serves any purpose, as your `INNER JOIN` should already be limiting the result set to cases only where `b.Brand_ID = pf2.BrandID`.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I am trying to update the Table:Brands; Field:Products to the COUNT of the Table:Product_Families; Field: Product_Families_ID.   I am wondering if I need to put this in a temp table first.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a non-scalar value to a scalar value. Your subquery could return a set of tuples because you are asking for a COUNT on each group. Run the subquery by itself:

```
(Select COUNT(pf.Product_Family_ID) 
   FROM Product_Families pf
   INNER JOIN Products p ON pf.Product_Family_ID = p.Product_Family_ID
   INNER JOIN Brands b2 on pf.BrandID = b2.Brand_ID
   WHERE 
      pf.Discontinued = 0 
      AND 
      pf.Live = 0 
      AND 
      p.Inventory > 0
      AND 
      pf.Brand <> ''
    GROUP BY b2.Brand, b2.Brand_ID)
```

and you will see what it returns. You probably want a count of all the records in the subquery: take out the groupings.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the help, here is the solution that I used.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
  /*Then it exists*/
  DROP TABLE #Temp

SELECT * INTO #Temp FROM (SELECT 
    b.Brand_ID, 
    b.Brand, 
    COUNT(pf.Product_Family_ID) PFBrandCount FROM Product_Families pf 
INNER JOIN Products p ON pf.Product_Family_ID = p.Product_Family_ID
INNER JOIN Brands b on pf.BrandID = b.Brand_ID
WHERE 
    pf.Discontinued = 0 
AND 
    pf.Live = 0 
AND 
    p.Inventory > 0
AND 
    pf.Brand <> ''
Group BY b.Brand, b.Brand_ID) data

Update b SET Products = #Temp.PFBrandCount
FROM BRANDS b
INNER JOIN #Temp ON b.Brand_ID = #Temp.Brand_ID       


DROP TABLE #Temp
```

Answer (score 0):

As @nicomp said, Your subquery will return more than one result so just filter out the result to specific brands.

Try this:

```
UPDATE b 
SET b.Products = Select number (SELECT COUNT(pf.Product_Family_ID) as number, b2.Brand_ID
                  FROM Product_Families pf
                  INNER JOIN Products p ON pf.Product_Family_ID = p.Product_Family_ID
                  INNER JOIN Brands b2 on pf.BrandID = b2.Brand_ID
                  WHERE 
                      pf.Discontinued = 0 
                      AND pf.Live = 0 
                      AND p.Inventory > 0
                      AND pf.Brand <> ''
                  GROUP BY 
                      b2.Brand, b2.Brand_ID) 
                  Where Brand_ID = b.Brand_ID
FROM Brands b
INNER JOIN Product_Families pf2 ON b.Brand_ID = pf2.BrandID
WHERE
    b.Brand_ID = pf2.BrandID
```

This is not optimized but this will fix your error.